# text files are displayed differently in different clients

Tags: c++, text, output, atom-editor, clion

I have a c++ program that creates a .txt file and writes output to it. When I open with it with different clients, in this case Clion, Atom, and Gedit, the displays are differently. I tried googling a solution or an explanation, but no luck so far.

This is in Atom
[image: This is how it looks in atom]
This is in Clion
[image: This is in Clion]
This is Gedit
[image: This is Gedit]

What is actually the problem? The way I am writing the output? The client? The encoding?

Extra: What would be the best format to output the displayed data? .txt, .log, others?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you write the file? Tabs or spaces?

Comment: mixture of both. I firstly tried just tabs, but the text was not aligned as I wanted, so I introduced some spaces.+

Comment: Tab size is application defined.

Comment: I would avoid tabs, especially if you want the output to look 'just so'.

Comment: @JohnFilleau, sorry about that mistake, the page number makes no difference. Is then a tab problem probably

Comment: If you want your output columns to line up with the headers, then you need the program interpreting your data to figure out some logical concept of what a column is. One common way to do this is with a spreadsheet program. Is it an option to write this in .csv format and open it in a spreadsheet? If this is going to be viewed on a terminal and you have the disk space, there's nothing wrong with saving spaces. If you must be able to view/edit this in a text editor, then spaces are the way to go.

Comment: @JohnFilleau thanks, I was considering using csv actually.  Thanks!

Comment: Spaces work, until someone uses a proportional width font where tabs would work better. No silver bullet since you can't control how folks configure their editor..